# Using sed to replace <? with <?php

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to programmatically replace `<?` with `<?php` in a bunch of file, but my sed regex isn't behaving like I expected. Can you tell me what's wrong with it?

I'm testing it on the command line here:

```
$ sed -e 's/<\?/<\?php/g'
<?
<?php?<?php
d
<?phpd<?php
```

Comment: What is your input, what is your output - that 'test case' is impossible to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the escapes on the ?:

```
sed -e 's/<?/<?php/g'
```

Comment: Yes, I think you do. The solution you posted will match an optional <, not a literal <?

Comment: Maybe it depends on the version of sed, but the `\?` in the version I am using is the optional character quantifier.  http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape the back reference in the replacement.

```
sed 's#<\?#<?php#'
```

In a pipe, to correct for doubling the php:

```
sed 's#<\?#<?php#g' | sed 's#phpphp#php#g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to use sed, or can you use perl as well?

```
perl -pi.tmp -e 's,^<\?(?!php),<?php,' *.php *.inc
rm *.tmp
```

I am using a negative look-ahead to avoid generating `<?phpphp` in cases where the files already start with the correct characters.

Answer (score 0):

This will also skip matching with `<?=$variable`:

```
sed -e 's/<?\([^=p]\)/<?php\1/g' -e 's/<?$/<?php/g'
```