# Sed to replace <? with <?php

Tags: php, regex, sed

I've got some *really* old code (php 5.1) that needs to run on a newer server.

New server has PHP 5.6, so any areas where

```
<?
```

is used to open the PHP context, those are not being interpreted correctly. I need to replace all instances of

```
<?
```

with

```
<?php
```

*except* where

```
<?
```

is already part of

```
<?php
```

My inital effort was to use backreferences and sed:

```
cat file.php | sed -i 's/<?([^php])/<?php\$1/g'
```

However, the () seems to break the match, and without it, I cannot have a proper back reference.

I was trying to get whatever was *after* PHP opening tag into the backreference, so I could turn lines like:

```
<?=$_COOKIE...
```

into

```
<?php=$_COOKIE...
```

And, please don't point me to: [Using sed to replace <? with <?php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022823/using-sed-to-replace-with-php). I already saw it, and it does not address the fact that I already have the new opening tag in some places and the old one in others. (One of the answers kind of does, but I would prefer not to create "phpphphphpphp" and have to search for that over and over to reduce it to "php"

Lastly, please forgive the weirdly spaced open and closing tags. SO cannot display them in line with the text, only if they are in a code block.

Comment: `[^php]` does not match any text that is not equal to `php`, it only matches 1 char that is either `p` or `h`. IMHO, you can't do that with sed regex reliably since it does not support lookarounds.

Comment: The proper regex woulld be something like this `<\?(?!php)`, but as @WiktorStribiżew stated, `sed` doesnt's support negative lookaheads.

Comment: I was not aware it didn't support negative lookarounds. Looks like I'll have to script this in Python.... thanks, gentlemen.

Comment: ummm `short_open_tag=On` ?

Comment: Please [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322304/regexp-to-fix-php-tags/38322609#38322609): *Enable the short tags with `short_open_tag=On` in `php.ini`*

Comment: Why not replace `<?\s` with `<?php` ?

Comment: I'm not on linux right now, so forgive me for working from memory and not testing it first `sed -Pe 's/<\?(\s)/<?php\1/g'`.

Comment: @coladict: the `-P` option doesn't exist with sed (only grep)

Comment: `<?` is short for `<?php` and `<?=` is short for `<?php echo`.  They are independent and there is NO `<?php=`

Comment: You're right. Checked the man page online, but it does have `-r` for the extended regex that should support `\s`. The other syntax with  `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: from php manual: *"5.4.0  The tag <?= is always available regardless of the short_open_tag ini setting."*. Conclusion, no problem with this one.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte:  Yes I know (that's why I said they were independent) , so no need to worry about that, just `<?\s`.  Seems like we keep coming back to `<?\s` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
sed 's/<?\(php\)*/<?php/g' file
```

In this case "php" is optional but is systematically overwritten if it's already here.

Or using a white-space character as suggests AbraCadaver since it seems to be mandatory after a short tag:

```
sed 's/<?\([[:space:]]\)/<?php\1/g' file
```

Limitation: this pattern can't know if `<?` or `<?php` is inside a string. Example:

```
echo 'abc <? def';
```

becomes:

```
echo 'abc <?php def';
```

---

A better way is to use PHP itself with the [tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php).

example:

```
$str = 'echo "blah"; <? echo "sblub"; ?> bluh';

$result = '';

foreach(token_get_all($str) as $tok) {
    $result .= ($tok[0] == 376) ? '<?php' : $tok[1]; 
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: I don't know SED, but why not replace `<?\s` with `<?php` ?

Comment: because sometimes there is whitespace there, and sometimes not.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: It's a good idea with `[[:blank:]]` in place of `\s` but I don't remember if `<?echo 'toto';?>` was allowed or not.

Comment: I like the token_get_all I didn't know one!

Comment: And `<?=$var?>` becomes `<?php=$var?>`

Comment: @DrDamnit: No, it won't parse as a PHP tag without whitespace.  So, `<?php=` is not valid either.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
https://regex101.com/r/tMkwCT/1

regex:

```
^<\?([^p\=])/gm
```

substitution:

```
<?php$1
```

explanation:
^ asserts position at start of a line
< matches the character < literally (case sensitive)
\? matches the character ? literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group ([^p\=])
Match a single character not present in the list below [^p\=]
p matches the character p literally (case sensitive)
\= matches the character = literally (case sensitive)
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

you can modify for your SED script

or you can enable `short_open_tag`
http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

`PHP also allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).`

update:
- https://regex101.com/r/tMkwCT/4 by @SamuelAialaFerreira
- https://regex101.com/r/tMkwCT/7 - removing ^ so it will check if the opening code is not at start of a line

Comment: This almost worked for me. I'm trying to run this script in a giant folder, and in this two cases they didn't work

<?print" I updated the link from regex101 could you please help me ? I'm a newbie in ER.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also changed the er to ^<\?([^pP\=]) because you could get <?php and <?PHP. Here the URL: https://regex101.com/r/tMkwCT/4

Thanks!